# In-memory file to intercept stdout on function call

Tags: unix, stdout

I've inherited this function that I have to call from my code. The function is
from a bizzare library in an arcane programming language -- so I cannot assume
almost anything about it, except for the fact that it prints some useful
infomation to stdout.

Let me simulate its effect with

```
void black_box(int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) std::cout << "x";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I want to intercept and use the stuff it outputs. To that end I redirect stdout
to a temporary file, call the `black_box`, then restore the stdout and read the
stuff from the temporary file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>


int main(void){
    int fd = open( "outbuff",  O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0600);

    // Redirect stdout to fd
    int tmp = dup(1);
    dup2( fd, 1);

        // Execute
        black_box(100);
        std::cout << std::flush;

    // Restore old stdout
    dup2(tmp, 1);

    // Read output from the outbuff flie
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd, &st);
    std::string buf;
    buf.resize(st.st_size);

    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, &buf[0], st.st_size);
    close(fd);

    std::cout << "Captured: " << buf << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This works. But creating a file on disk for such a task is not something I'm
proud of. Can I make something like a file, but in-memory?

Before suggesting a pipe, please consider what would happen if
`black_box` overflows its buffer.  And no, I need it single-threaded --
starting an extra process/thread defeats the whole purpose ot what I'm trying
to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to intercept and use the stuff it outputs.
>
> [...] please consider what would happen if black_box overflows its buffer.

I see two alternatives.

1. If you know the maximum size of the output, and the size is not too excessive, use the [`socketpair`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socketpair.html) instead of `pipe`. Unlike pipes, sockets allow to change the size of the egress/ingress buffers.
2. Use a temporary file on `/tmp`. In normal case it will not touch disk (unless system is swapping). There are few functions for the purpose, for example [`mkstemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html) (or [`tmpfile`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tmpfile.html)).